# How to Vectorize initial conditions

Tags: vectorization, octave

I'm trying to vectorize the initial conditions `(x)` and `(y)` to plot multiple strange attractors at different initial conditions while having each initial condition have a separate color plot.  But I'm not sure how to vectorize the initial conditions and have each initial condition plot be a separate color.

My thoughts were to have **x** and **y** be a vector x=[7.4,6.3,3.4,5.4,4.5] y=[.6,.3,.8,.3,.14] and each x and y initial condition create their own plot with a different color (but that doesn't work because it wants one value not multiple values). See below what one of the x(k) and y(k) initial value plots would look like.

[image: plot]

Working code below not vectorized:

```
x(1)=[7.4];
y(1)=[.6];
a = -1.24458;
b = -1.25191;
c = -1.815908;
d = -1.90866;

maxiter = 10000;
z = linspace(1,maxiter+1,maxiter+1);
for k=1:maxiter

% Clifford Attractors

  x(k+1) = sin(a*y(k)) + c*cos(a*x(k));
  y(k+1) = sin(b*x(k)) + d*cos(b*y(k));
end

scatter(x,y,'.')
```

Ps: I'm using 64bit Ubuntu Linux Octave 4.2.2 which is similar to Matlab

Comment: You cannot vectorize a recursive definition like this.

Comment: Yoy can preallocate x and y to speed up the calculation. `y=zeros(1,maxiter);x=zeros(1,maxiter);`

Comment: ...to prevent GNU Octave from reallocating and copying the increasing matrix every loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a matrix instead of a vector, and treat each row as one iteration. To speed up things a little bit we can allocate the matrix at the start. To plot the different runs we just have to iterate over them and use a different color each time:

```
x0=[7.4,6.3,3.4,5.4,4.5];
y0=[.6,.3,.8,.3,.14];
a = -1.24458;
b = -1.25191;
c = -1.815908;
d = -1.90866;

maxiter = 1000;
z = linspace(1,maxiter+1,maxiter+1);
N = numel(x0);
x = [x0;NaN(maxiter, N)];
y = [x0;NaN(maxiter, N)];
for k=1:maxiter

% Clifford Attractors

  x(k+1,:) = sin(a*y(k,:)) + c*cos(a*x(k,:));
  y(k+1,:) = sin(b*x(k,:)) + d*cos(b*y(k,:));
end

colors = 'rgbymcwk';
hold on
for n=1:N
    scatter(x(:,n), y(:,n), ['.',colors(1+mod(n,numel(colors)))])
end
```